# click has no effect after ajax call

Tags: puppeteer

Why my second click has no effect after ajax call? It's an input, it's not focus when I check with `headless: false`, I thought I've used waitForNavigation and it should worked?

```
//select country, ajax call
  await page.waitForSelector('input[data-short="my"]')
  await page.click('input[data-short="my"]')

  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" })

  //no effect here? I'm sure my selector is correct
  await page.click('#sku_number')
  await page.keyboard.type('123')
```

Comment: `Why my second click has no effect after ajax call?` How can we know without having URL to test with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion that may get things working for you: add this in before that call to `click`:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#sku_number'); // Ensure the component is visible
await page.click('#sku_number'); // Now click the component
```